# Inflated ImageView with attribute Onclick

Tags: android

i want that when i click on `ImageView` two things happen: 
Background of `ImageView` change and a `Toast` must appear on the screnn  , so i use `Selector` (**imgPressed.xml**) to change Background and method onImageClick in MainActivity to launch Toast.
but it shows me this error : ***java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onImageClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'imageView'***

Note : the ImageView exist in a layout Resource File named pause.xml. I noticed that when i use ImageView directly in content_main.xml (layout of MainActivitiy.java) it works , but when i inflate pause.xml it shows me Error.

Code Java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout Rel_main_game;
    View pauseButton;


    public void onImageClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main.xml);

        LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        pauseButton = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.pause, null, false);

        Rel_main_game = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        Rel_main_game.addView(pauseButton);
    }
}
```

imgpressed.xml :

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pauseimg"/>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pauseimgclicked"/>
</item>
</selector>
```

pause.xml :

```html
 <ImageView
        android:onClick="onImageClick"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pauseimgS"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@drawable/imgpressed"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code example seems to be incomplete. But anyway you may define the onclick action programmatically instead of using the XML attribute `onClick`. You can do this by setting an `OnClickListener` on your View after inflating it, and call your `onImageClick` method from there:

```
pauseButton = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.pause, null, false);
pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onImageClick(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: but what about imgpressed.xml i want also that background change when i press ...

Comment: Can't see an issue with that, except you could try to remove the `focusableInTouchMode` attribute.

Comment: you just prposed to call method in other method ^^, I think attribute onclick does not search for methodes in place where his view is inflated hmm